# How to plot ohlc candlestick with datetime in matplotlib using mplfinance candlestick_ohlc?

Tags: python, matplotlib, candlestick-chart

I am trying to plot 5 minutes historical candlesticks and I have these problems:
Doing that with daily candlesticks data it shows the correct result: [1-day chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZKz3K.png)
but with 5m it looks like that: [5 minutes chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GPdao.png)

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
        df['date'] = df['date'].apply(mpl_dates.date2num)
        df = df.astype(float)
        plt.style.use('dark_background')
        levels = self.getLevels()
        ax = plt.subplot2grid((1, 1), (0, 0), rowspan=6, colspan=4)
        candlestick_ohlc(ax,df.values,width=0.4, \
                   colorup='green', colordown='red', alpha=1.0)


        #ax.grid(True)
        # Setting labels 
        ax.set_xlabel('Date')
        ax.set_ylabel('Price')
        # Formatting Date
        date_format = mpl_dates.DateFormatter("%d/%m/%y %H:%M")
        ax.xaxis_date()
        ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(date_format)
        #fig.autofmt_xdate()
        #fig.tight_layout()
        plt.xticks(rotation=90)
        for level in levels:
            plt.hlines(level[1],xmin=df['date'][level[0]],\
               xmax=max(df['date']),colors='blue')
        plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran your code, but it did not work as expected. Currently mpl_finance is deprecated and mplfinance is recommended. mplfinance has the ability to draw trendlines etc. and can draw partial horizontal lines. To draw an interrupted line, put the start and end points in a list and deal with it. In my example, I make a list of the starting price and the high price and set them to alines. Please refer to this page for a detailed [explanation](https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance/blob/master/examples/using_lines.ipynb).

```
import mplfinance as mpf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd

df = yf.download("AAPL", start="2021-10-25", end="2021-10-29", interval='5m', progress=False)
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
df.index = df.index.tz_localize(None)

df = df[:200] # Limit data to emphasize the lines in the graph.

o_lines = []
m_lines = []
for c in df.columns[:4]:
    if c == 'Open':
        idx, price1, end, price2 = df[c].head(1).index[0], df[c].head(1)[0], df[c].tail(1).index[0], df[c].head(1)[0] 
        o_lines.append((idx, price1))
        o_lines.append((end, price2))
    if c == 'High':
        idx, price1, end, price2 = df.loc[df[c].idxmax()].name, df.loc[df[c].idxmax()][c], df[c].tail(1).index[0], df.loc[df[c].idxmax()][c] 
        m_lines.append((idx, price1))
        m_lines.append((end, price2))
        # print(m_lines)

mpf.plot(df, type='candle', alines=dict(alines=[o_lines, m_lines], colors=['b','r'], linewidths=2, alpha=0.4), style='yahoo')
```

[image]

Comment: Please refer to the official reference for a wealth of examples. If my answer is helpful to you, please accept it by clicking the check mark next to the answer.

Comment: thanks but the problem here was actually the candlesticks (see pictures)

Comment: My answer is also a candlestick graph, but what is the difference?

Comment: Still have some problems with plotting a_lines, please look at my answer below this+

Comment: A continuous line is in that format, but a single line is, for example, [(start date,high),(end date,high)]. So if you want to draw multiple single lines, they will be [[(start date,high),(end date,high)],[(start date,high),(end date,high)]]. Please enable the print statement `m_lines` to check the data.

Comment: Thanks, i changed levels to look like this : [(Timestamp('2021-10-01 20:15:00+0000', tz='UTC'), 31.58), (Timestamp('2021-10-01 22:15:00+0000', tz='UTC'), 32.29), (Timestamp('2021-10-02 01:15:00+0000', tz='UTC'), 32.72), (Timestamp('2021-10-02 02:00:00+0000', tz='UTC'), 32.0), (Timestamp('2021-10-02 22:15:00+0000', tz='UTC'), 33.02)], but i still get a continuous line

Comment: [[start_day, 150],[end_day, 150]] It will be a multiple list. You can now draw a horizontal line (because the price will not change) and make sure the lists are nested.

Comment: I m getting this error by running the code below, i did it like you said for multiple single lines  'Validator'   : lambda value: _alines_validator(value) },

Comment: If you look at the code below, you will see that the start and end are added to the list as a single tuple. Please break it into two lines, one for the start to add to the list, and one for the end to add to the list. `lines.append((idx, price1));lines.append((end, price2))`

Comment: still getting the same error though.

Comment: Update all current codes with your questions. We have nothing to suggest in this exchange as it is.

Answer (score 0):

```
    lines = []
    for level in levels:
        idx, price1, end, price2 = ohlc['date'][level[0]], level[1], max(ohlc['date']),level[1]
        lines.append((idx, price1,end, price2))  
         
        print(lines)

    mpf.plot(ohlc, type='candle',alines=dict(alines=lines,colors = 'y',linewidths=2, alpha=0.3), volume=True,panel_ratios=(4,1),addplot=indicators)

(
    Timestamp("2021-10-01 20:15:00+0000", tz="UTC"),
    31.58,
    Timestamp("2021-10-03 21:00:00+0000", tz="UTC"),
    31.58,
),
(
    Timestamp("2021-10-01 22:15:00+0000", tz="UTC"),
    32.29,
    Timestamp("2021-10-03 21:00:00+0000", tz="UTC"),
    32.29,
),
(
    Timestamp("2021-10-02 01:15:00+0000", tz="UTC"),
    32.72,
    Timestamp("2021-10-03 21:00:00+0000", tz="UTC"),
    32.72,
),
(
    Timestamp("2021-10-02 02:00:00+0000", tz="UTC"),
    32.0,
    Timestamp("2021-10-03 21:00:00+0000", tz="UTC"),
    32.0,
),
(
    Timestamp("2021-10-02 22:15:00+0000", tz="UTC"),
    33.02,
    Timestamp("2021-10-03 21:00:00+0000", tz="UTC"),
    33.02,
),
```

]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).